# Need helping making the code for income tax calculator more efficient on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I built a simple income tax calculator as a project for my class which includes all 50 states and DC. My code seems extra, I have only included the code for Florida. How can I make this efficient? Additionally, are there any areas where I can include for or while statement?

```
state = input("Enter state: ")

if state == "Florida" or "florida" or "FL" or "fl":
    def fl(fl_income):
        return 0
        

    def print_info(fl_income, afterTaxes):
        fedTaxes_paid = afterTaxes
        print("Total federal taxes you pays: $", round(fedTaxes_paid, 2))
        fl_loss = fl(fl_income)
        ssc_tax = income * 0.062
        medi_tax = income * 0.0145
        fica = ssc_tax + medi_tax
        final_income = income - fedTaxes_paid - fl_loss - fica
        print("Total Florida state taxes you pay: $", round(fl_loss, 2))
        print("Total FICA tax deducted: $", round(fica, 2))
        print("Income after fed taxes: $", round(income - fedTaxes_paid, 2))
        print("Income after Florida state taxes: $", round(final_income, 2))

    status = input("Enter your filing status: ")
    income = float(input("Enter your income: $"))

    if status == "single":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit() 
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85525) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "married filed jointly" or "filed jointly":
    
        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit() 
        elif income <= 19750:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 80250:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (income - 19750) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 171050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (income - 80250) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 326600:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 414700:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (income - 326600) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 622050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (income - 414700) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (518400 - 414700) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 622050) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        
        print("")

    elif status == "married filed separately" or "filed separately":
    
        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit() 
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 311025:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 19750) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (311025 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 311025) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        
        print("")
   
    elif status == "head of household":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit() 
        elif income <= 14100:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 53700:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (income - 14100) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85500:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (income - 53700) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85500) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        
        print("")
```

Comment: I didn’t go through your code in detail but be aware that that the IRS calculates taxes based on income in chunks of $25 for low amounts and $50 for larger amounts, there for an income of say 45,549 would fall into the 45,500 - 48,550 range and be calculated at the marginal rate * 45,525. As far as coding, I wouldn’t perform the same calculation in multiple places. 14100*0.10 should be assigned to a variable and added in as incomes rise.

Comment: thanks for the help but I changed my question. I used taxact.com and it showed that the federal income fit into the tax bracket. Like 50k was in 22%. But what do you mean in aspect of coding, I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: The basic idea is to not have the same piece of code repeated in your program. If you look at your code you much that is repeated for example the calculation 14100 * 0.10 occurs 6 times in your code. There are several ways to handle this and thinking about how to solve it is an invaluable skill for you to develop. You could create a function to handle it. What parameters are common for your calculations? Top of bracket, bottom of bracket, rate and tax on lower bracket? Think about it and if you get stuck text me back.